# Servlerless framework how to get AWS subnet and security group id dynamically

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#vpc-configuration) to deploy a Lambda to AWS with Typescript
When attaching Lambda to an existing VPC we need to provide the Subnet and Security group ids.

1. Is there any way to get this value dynamically for my cloud account?
2. Is it safe to save these actual ids in the git repo, but I want to avoid it?

**index.ts** as below

```
import user from './schema'
import { handlerPath } from '@libs/handler-resolver'

export default {
  handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.createuser`,
  events: [
    {
      http: {
        method: 'post',
        path: 'user',
        request: {
          schemas: {
            'application/json': user,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  vpc: {
    subnetIds: [
      'subnet-1_ID',
      'subnet-2_ID',
      'subnet-3_ID',
    ], // Replace with your actual subnet IDs
    securityGroupIds: ['sg-1_ID'], // Replace with your actual security group ID
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your Subnets and Security groups deployed via CloudFormation? If so you could output them from the CloudFormation stack and reference them directly in your serverless config. More info [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-cloudformation-outputs).

If they are not, then you can get them using the AWS CLI and either set them as env vars or pass them in as parameters. Then you can reference them directly from within the serverless config.

Here are some commands you can use to get the IDs. Be sure your region is set correctly and this assumes you will run it once for each value you need:

Security Groups:

`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=<<REPLACE_WITH_NAME_OF_SECURITY_GROUP>> --query "SecurityGroups[*].GroupId" --output text`

Subnets (Since your VPC already exists, you can use that ID):

`aws --region us-east-1 ec2 describe-subnets --filter Name=vpc-id,Values=<<REPLACE_WITH_VPC_ID>> --query "Subnets[*].SubnetId"`

The subnet command will return all of the subnets attached to that VPC. If you need specific ones you should tag them appropriately and use that to filter them. In my opinion, using CloudFormation is the best option here as it makes it the easiest.